# Is there a way to convert spreadsheet table to JSON format by rows & columns?

Tags: json, database, spreadsheet

I am having trouble filling up my database with existing spreadsheet. My objective is to import these data into a react application for detailed analysis.

The data is large, consists of more than 10,000 entries as follows.
[image: Spread Sheet Table, I can change the column titles.]

Here is the spreadsheet sample.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gfUnloNzqXXfNi8VzoRXDkwax6pVvlkRPkUqbCQ6AtQ/edit?usp=sharing

I am wondering if it is possible to convert these into JSON Format by column and row.

```
( "n": [
         { "new" : [
            "cxtype": "PF,
            "name" : "this is a name",
            "phonenumber" : "0000000000", "...." ]
          },
          { "upgrade" : [
            "cxtype": "PF,
            "name" : "this is a name",
            "phonenumber" : "0000000000", "...." ]
          } ....]
      )
```

I am wondering if this can be done through JavaScript, but I am willing to learn other languages if there are ways.

Please help. Thank you :)

Comment: Please adhere to the [mcve] guidelines more closely, preferably giving the illustrative input in a form which can easily be used for testing, and likewise giving the corresponding output.  Exporting a spreadsheet as a CSV or TSV file would work.

Comment: @peak thank you, I have recreated a sample and edited the question for easier comprehension of my problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the link you provided is private.  Also, it looks as though the link is to a spreadsheet.  Can't you export it to some textual format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the requirements are not very clear, especially as the output that is shown as expected is not valid JSON and does not correspond so closely to the sample input, but hopefully the following will get you on your way.

First, I "exported" the Google spreadsheet to a TSV file.  This results in a DOS-formatted file, which is why some extra processing to handle the "\r" may be needed (e.g. as shown below).

Second, I ran jq with the -nrR options, and the following jq program:

```
foreach (inputs|split("\t") | select( all(.[]; . == "" or . == "\r") | not )) as $in (null;
   if $in[2] == "CUSTOMER TYPE" then .ready = true | .emit = null
   elif $in[2] == null then .ready=false | .emit = null
   elif .ready and ($in[1] != "") then (.emit=$in)
   else (.ready=false) | .emit = null
   end;
   select(.emit).emit )
| [.[1,2,5]] as [$key, $cxtype, $name]
| { ($key): { $cxtype, $name }}
```

This produces the following output, which is very close to what is shown in the Q:

```
{"NEW":{"cxtype":"pf","name":"this is a name"}}
{"UPGRADE":{"cxtype":"pf","name":"this is a name"}}
{"PA":{"cxtype":"","name":""}}
{"PB":{"cxtype":"","name":""}}
```